# Incidence Matrices

Tags: matrices

Sears airways is a budget airline. On a particular day, it has flights connecting 4 cities, Singapore, Taipei, Seoul and Tokyo. The flights can be represented by the following network, with arrows indicating the direction of the flights.
[map of network)

The incidence matrix shows whether it is possible to travel directly from one city to another.

```
             End of flight      start of flight
             A   B   C   D 
             0   1   0   0      A
```

M=            1   0   1   1      B
                 1   0   0   1      C
                 0   1   1   0      D 
a)Using Matrix multiplication calculate M^2.
Explain what entries in M^2 represent
b)Calculate M^2 + M . This matrix does not contain zero entry. What is the meaning of absence of zero entry?

My answer:
M^2=
           1  0  1  1
           1  2  1  1 
           0  2  1  0
           2  0  1  2

Entry 1 means one return jorney from the start of flight to end of flight is possible. 
Entry 2 means 2 return journeys are possible. am I right?
 M^2+M=      1  1  1  1
             2  1  2  2
             1  2  1  1
             2  1  2  2
I don't know how to make sense of this matrix.
what does the absence of zero mean?
Please help. Thank you .
Ashwini

Comment: The matrices are not readable at all, as you can see. Please rewrite the matrices, and you can use MathJax for that.

Comment: i had uploaded picture which does not show here

Comment: I would advice not to post links to pictures -- posts on this forum should be self-contained. Please type out the matrices with MathJax.